# Set a range of selection for Streamlit date slider

Tags: python, streamlit

Hi I would like to set a range for the slider - for example 1 day or 3 days. At the moment there is no set range so user can choose range from 2 to more than 1000 days.

[image: Please click to see the current status]

```py
def df_filter(message,df):
   dates_selection = st.slider('%s' % (message),
                               min_value = min(df['Date']),
                               max_value = max(df['Date']),
                               value =(min(df['Date']),max(df['Date'])))
   mask = df['Date'].between(*dates_selection)
   number_of_result = df[mask].shape[0]
   filtered_df = df[mask]
   return filtered_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
   df = pd.DataFrame(heartrate_new)

   st.header('Datetime Filter')
   filtered_df = df_filter('Move sliders to filter dataframe',df)
   filtered_df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace = True)

   container1 = st.container()
   with container1:
      st.header('Data Frame')
      st.write(filtered_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The range of the slider is coming from the difference between the `min_value` and `max_value` that you’re setting. You can set the `max_value` to be `min(df['Date'])` + 3 days (or however many days you want).